# Deleting sharepoint list items with pnp results in bad request

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-item, delete, pnp-js-core

Running pnp in modern script editor spfx web part, can add items, get items from a list, but cannot delete items from a list:

```
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('List Name').items
    .filter('Title eq Test')
    .delete()
```

Error shows up in console:

> DELETE
>   https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamIT/spfx-sfd/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List
>   Name')/items?$filter=Title eq Test 400 (Bad Request)

If I take the url and drop it into Chrome, it returns the item properly.

What on earth am I missing with something this simple?  Lots of documentation in pnp on how to delete a list, didn't find much for list items, is there something unique that must be submitted with a delete to get it to operate properly?

Comment: You could refer my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You delete it using batch request as below:

```
var batch = $pnp.sp.createBatch();

var list = $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List Name");

list.items.filter("Title eq 'test'").get().then((items) =>{ 

  items.forEach(i =>{
    list.items.getById(i["ID"]).inBatch(batch).delete().then(r => {
      console.log("deleted");
    });
  });

  batch.execute().then(() => console.log("All deleted"));

});
```

Comment: This worked for me, looks like a syntax issue kept the above code from functioning:

var batch = $pnp.sp.createBatch();
 var varTitle = "Title eq '" + userObj + "'";

 var list = $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("<List Name>");

 list.items.filter(varTitle).get().then((items) =>{
  items.forEach(i =>{
   list.items.getById(i["ID"]).inBatch(batch).delete().then(r => {
    console.log("deleted");
   });
  });

  batch.execute().then(() => console.log("Deleted item"));
 });

Comment: @Dodge1350 - cool, happy to help. You can accept it as answer by ticking the checkbox besides the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code:

```
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('List Name').items
    .filter('Title eq "Test"')
    .delete()
```

Comment: You cannot do like this, pnpjs don't have delete method on filter